# Unable to collect values from array URL in PHP

Tags: php

3rd party passes the details to the URL. It makes get request to the URL with details as url-encoded HTTP query parameters.

following is the URL sample :
    http://_______.com/customer_missed_call.php?CallSid=e9536ef16460727558c0db17349021b0&From=09513325525&To=08039511763&Direction=incoming&DialCallDuration=0&StartTime=2016-02-10+14%3A56%3A17&EndTime=0000-00-00+00%3A00%3A00&CallType=callattempt&DialWhomNumber=&Created=Wed%2C+10+Feb+2016+14%3A56%3A17&flow_id=67475&tenant_id=24683&CallFrom=09513325525&CallTo=8039511763&ForwardedFrom=&CurrentTime=2016-02-10+14%3A56%3A17

I want to collect the values of 'CallSid' and 'From' from this url.

I tried following codes

```
<?php echo $_GET; ?>
```

and

```
<?php echo utf8_decode(urldecode($_GET)); ?>
```

and

```
$URL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  $parsedURL=parse_url($URL);
  $URLQ=$parsedURL['CallSid'];
  echo $parsedURL;
```

but did not got values for any one of the above code. Please try to give effective solution for the above problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your URL is corrupted shouldn't it start with `http://_______.com/customer_missed_call.php?CallSid=...` ?

Answer (score 1):

The "?"-delimiter is missing in the URL

**Edit:** Please provide how you call the URL (the code for the request).

`$_GET['CallSid'];` should do the trick normally

Comment: the ? is there. But still unable to get the values?

Answer (score 1):

They are missing an `?` after the `.php`

It should be like this:

```
http://_______.com/customer_missed_call.php?CallSid=e9536ef16460727558c0db17349021b0&From=09513325525&To=08039511763&Direction=incoming&DialCallDuration=0&StartTime=2016-02-10+14%3A56%3A17&EndTime=0000-00-00+00%3A00%3A00&CallType=callattempt&DialWhomNumber=&Created=Wed%2C+10+Feb+2016+14%3A56%3A17&flow_id=67475&tenant_id=24683&CallFrom=09513325525&CallTo=8039511763&ForwardedFrom=&CurrentTime=2016-02-10+14%3A56%3A17
```

Comment: question mark is there. i forgot to add it in code. but problem remains same

Answer (score 0):

One of the things that is likely causing an issue is that parse_url returns an array with predefined keys. The key for the query is 'query' (`$parsedURL['query'];`)

However using the $_GET method is much more easy to read and is easier than getting the query string and manually parsing it. To access values in it, you also need to specify a key, not just call the array itself. e.g.:

```
$callSID = $_GET['CallSid'];
$from = $_GET['From'];
```

Hope that helps